# can I declare intent variable in fortran module?

Tags: fortran

can I declare intent variable in fortran module?
I want to make common module which can be called other subroutine

```
module fmod
real b
integer n, i
integer, dimension(6), intent(inout) :: indata1
real, dimension(7,8), intent(inout) :: indata2
end module fmod

subroutine temp_f(indata1, indata2)
use fmod

do i=1,8
   print *, indata4(i)
end do

end
```

Answer (score 8):

No, intent is for subroutine arguments, not module variables.   Module variables are normally available to any entity that "use"s them.  You can declare them to be "private" which will  block their visibility outside of the module.  Perhaps you are thinking of a module as an include file, which copies source code lines for compilation where they are copied.  That is not the concept of a module ... it is an independent source code entity.

Although it is outside of the language standard, many Fortran compilers support the use of include files via "#include" starting in the first column.   With some compilers use a filetype "F90" (upper-case).  With others you have to use a compiler option to run the C-style pre-processor.  There is a small risk that this usage will make your code less portable.

Comment: Yes, you can. This form of include is standard Fortran 90 statement, not a preprocessor macro.